# TCL script not working anymore

Tags: tcl, cadence

I used to run a tcl script for the Cadence tools on a server, however, now the script fails to run.
The script is based on the following one:

```
#### Template Script for RTL->Gate-Level Flow
#### all basic steps except for DFT-scan

#### Fill in the <...> fields for your module 
#### and update library  search paths for your system

if {[file exists /proc/cpuinfo]} {
  sh grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
  sh grep "cpu MHz"    /proc/cpuinfo
}

#### Set up
set DESIGN test
set SYN_EFF medium
set MAP_EFF medium
set DATE test
set global_map_report 1
set map_fancy_names 1
set iopt_stats 1

set SYN_PATH "."
set _OUTPUTS_PATH outputs_${DATE}
set _LOG_PATH logs_${DATE}
set _REPORTS_PATH reports_${DATE}

set_attribute lib_search_path {. ./lib} / 
set_attribute hdl_search_path {. ./rtl} /
set_attribute information_level 7 /
set_attribute map_timing true /

set_attribute retime_reg_naming_suffix __retimed_reg /
set_attribute library lib
... continues
```

First I open a `csh` in order to run a csh script to setup the Cadence tools on the server, then I run `source script.tcl`. This used to work, however, now it fails with the following error:

> Missing ].

And if I comment the first `if`:

> set: Syntax Error.

What may have changed in the server for this to happen and how can I fix this? The script did not change, so its syntax is correct.

Comment: Do you `source script.tcl` in csh?

Comment: I was trying to, but in fact I forgot to run the cadence tool first, as in the answer from timrau

Comment: Sounds too good to be true. How did the "csh script to setup the Cadence tools" look like?  Did it bring you into Cadence tool instead of staying in csh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comments in code described, you should call `source script.tcl` inside the tool, not in `csh` which doesn't understand Tcl syntax, nor in `tclsh` which doesn't understand those Cadence-specific Tcl commands.

Also, the two line

```
sh grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
sh grep "cpu MHz"    /proc/cpuinfo
```

should be

```
exec grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
exec grep "cpu MHz"    /proc/cpuinfo
```

since `exec` is the correct Tcl command for calling shell commands.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to call `rc` before running the script.